# Android - Specify needed storage available to install app

Tags: android, storage, manifest

Is there any way I can specify the minimum free space user has to have prior to install my Android app?

Let's say my application uses 10 mb... But I want to prevent users who have less than 20 mb to install my app... Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't control such storage requirements via the Play Store.

Of course when you get to run the first time, you can check the available storage, and put up a dialog suggesting that the user clear out some storage to bet a better experience with your app.